# Why does my REST endpoint URI for a sharepoint list column return an empty value

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint

I'm trying to request a column (referenced as "Numéro de ticket" in my code) from the list "TestArmand" to create a new unique value.
The problem is that my URI request return an empty value instead of the column (it return undefined in console but there is no error).

Here is the whole Jquery request:

```
        $.ajax({
                    url: appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('TestArmand')/fields/getByTitle('Numéro de ticket')", //my rest request, the base web url is automatically filled with appWebUrl
                    type: "GET",
                    async: false,
                    headers:    
                        {
                            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                        },
                    success: function (data) 
                        {
                            array = data.d.results; //array is the final result where my column is supposed to be
                        },
        
                    error: function (err) 
                        {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
        
                });
        console.log("TestArray:");//for debug
        console.log(array); //for debug
        return array;
```

I mostly used microsoft documentation as a reference [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/determine-sharepoint-rest-service-endpoint-uris?tabs=csom)

I'm also pretty sure it has something to do with the URI since when i remove the fields option i get the whole list in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `data.d` and not `data.d.result`

It's working on my site.

```
$.ajax({
    url: appWebUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestArmand')/fields/getByTitle('Numéro de ticket')",
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers:
        {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
    success: function (data) 
        {
            array = data.d; //array is the final result where my column is supposed to be
        },

    error: function (err) 
        {
            console.log(err);
        }

});
console.log("TestArray", array);
```

[image]

Why using a synchronous request and not process the data in the success callback?

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, as for the synchronous request i actually have no idea of what i'm doing, i pasted it to be honest and it's been a week since i'm googling stuff to understand.